Flutter Quill Editor type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
I am trying to get this to not get this error. I am for some reason getting an error where the decode and add json to the document is giving the error in the image.
`//Creates a new controller for each Note to be displayed
  QuillController newController(int index, String description) {
  _quillscontroller.add(QuillController.basic());
  _quillscontroller[index].readOnly = true;
  List jsonText = jsonDecode(description);
  _quillscontroller[index].document = Document.fromJson(jsonText);

  return _quillscontroller[index];
}`

An android application where there are multiple editors open from Quill Flutter.

Change List jsonText to String jsonText

_quillscontroller[index].document = Document.fromJson(jsonText); requires a type cast to List then so Im back where I started. Thanks for the help though
